# Data set of French Communes

Tags: data-request, france

I'm looking for a data set with the names and INSEE (ID code) for all the French communes.

I am hoping to find a data set for the entire country.  So far I have found that Wikipedia has it on the department level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for (at insee.fr):

[Liste des communes existantes au 1er janvier 2016](https://www.insee.fr/fr/information/2114819#titre-bloc-6)

Answer (score 0):

you can find the information you need in the Geofla® database. [You can find it and explore it here on OpenDataSoft](https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/geoflar-communes-2015%40public/table/) among with geolocation or population for every commune.

Disclaimer: I work at OpenDataSoft